# Schedule Jenkins Build Execution During Specific Times using Build periodically: (* * * * * *)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Schedule Jenkins Build Execution During Specific Times using Build periodically: (* * * * * *)?

For example: * * * * * * will execute builds continuously,

Is there a way to use the above approach but to run builds continuously between lets say 9am until 11pm.

Example:
Monday: time of execution: 9am until 11pm. 
Tuesday: time of execution: 9am until 11pm.

Comment: `* 9-23 * * *` ... It's basically just cron job syntax.

Comment: Your examples for build1 and build2 are identical. Did you mis-type something?

Comment: @Tom Lord sorry now updated my question

Comment: OK, and here's my updated answer: `* 9-23 * * 1` and `* 9-23 * * 2`. Again, this is just cron job syntax.

Comment: [Here is a good website to play with cron syntax](https://crontab.guru/#*_9-23_*_*_1).

Comment: @Tom Lord thanks for the answer and great link! thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run jobs between 9am - 11pm *every* day, you could use the following:

```
* 9-23 * * *
```

To run jobs between 9am - 11pm *only on Monday*, you can use:

```
* 9-23 * * 1
```

And likewise for Tuesday:

```
* 9-23 * * 2
```

[This website](https://crontab.guru/#*_9-23_*_*_1) is a great resource for experimenting with cron job formats, and seeing a "human translation" for the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following cron expression :  **H 9-23 * * ***

To build your own new cron expression keep the following link handy and test in Jenkins:
**https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html**

Comment: Jenkins doesn't support Quartz cron format, I believe?

Comment: Yes it doesn't. I cross checked and updated it. Thank you.